What is the fastest fixed landing gear airplane?
Interested in knowing what the fastest fixed gear airplane is and the performance of such aircraft.

Someone has voted to close this question as low quality. That is currently true because this question needs a lot more detail and specificity on what they want. Especially an age range.
I put the answer I was able to find but perhaps it's not the best suited for this question.

Perhaps the fastest fixed-gear aircraft was the Lockheed XFV. It was  powered by a 5,332 hp (3,976 kW) Allison YT40-A-6 turboprop engine driving three-bladed contra-rotating propellers, and had a top speed of 580mph (500 kn).
 source
It has tiny wheels on it's tailfin, and was intended to take off and land vertically.
More conventionally, the WW2 German Junkers Ju 87 Stuka is said to have been able to dive at over 400mph.
 source
Diving at this speed was obviously part of its operational envelope. However, in level flight their top speed was only a little over 230mph.

"And if you think that looks strange ..." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNECMA_Coléoptère

Perhaps not what the OP was thinking of, but the Schneider Trophy was run at times from 1913 to 1931, with the fastest finish at 340 mph.
Briefly looking over this list, the Macchi M.C.72 (another seaplane) appears to be the last fixed gear record holder.

That's very interesting, wasn't expecting that. Now I have two more questions lol, are floats considered "landing gear" and does floats provide less drag than tires?...posting both as separate post....

For contemporary planes, a Google search gives these results.

Cessna Corvalis TTx (Cessna 400)

It has a cruise speed of 235 knots true airspeed at 25k feet which is also listed as the top speed for some reason.
Performance of this plane -

Rate of climb: 1,400 ft/min
Max Speed (85% at 25,000 ft): 235 kts
Economy Cruise Speed (55% at 25,000 ft): 208 kts
Range at Max Cruise Speed (85% at 25,000 ft): 825 nm
Range at Economy Cruise Speed (55% at 25,000 ft): 1,250 nm
Service ceiling: 25,000 ft (7,600 m)

Not the best source for proving that this is the fastest fixed gear propeller plane but there's many other links that are saying the same.
(Source claiming it is the fastest)
(Performance figures)
